# Is there any drawback of MIXED replication mode?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5, mysqlbinlog

So, recent mysql server allows three types of replication mode: STATEMENT, ROW, MIXED. They all have pros/cons, and I pick the mode according to site characteristics.

When I get a replication error I sometimes need to examine the binlog files using `mysqlbinlog`, so I tend to use MIXED mode. ROW based replication doesn't let you see it because contents is not very readable. I'm thinking MIXED mode is 'best of both worlds'.

I haven't yet seen a lot of discussion regarding MIXED mode, much less drawbacks of using it. Can someone tell me few reasons to be cautious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some disadvantages

- For you MyISAM users out there, ***concurrent inserts are prohibited***.
- Data changes cannot be read unless you use [mysqlbinlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbinlog.html) with the options [--base64-output=DECODE-ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_base64-output) and [--verbose](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_verbose).
- BLOB data is written "as is" rather than the SQL that created the BLOB
- For more information, s[ee the MySQL Documentati](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-sbr-rbr.html#replication-sbr-rbr-rbr-disadvantages)on

Comment: Should be noted that these disadvantages are specific to row based logging, and that if you're already logging rows then you'll already be having these drawbacks.